# Unable to assign value to array in prange

Tags: python, c++, malloc, openmp, cython

I'm trying to allcate each thead a separate array. But when I try to assign value to it gives me error: **error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]**
Here's code:

```
cdef void test(int size,int num,int len,int height,int *f,int n_f):
    cdef int k
    cdef Node* tree_root
    cdef int i
    cdef int *a

    for i in prange(num,nogil=True,num_threads=2):
        a=<int *>malloc(sizeof(int)*size)
        srand(rand())
        #a[0]=rand()%len #if uncommented gives error
        with gil:
            for k in range(size):#if uncommented gives error
                a[k]=rand()%len
```

Couldn't understand the problem why assignment not allowed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug to me. I can reproduce it with `cython` version `0.20.1post0` on Ubuntu `14.04.4`. It is caused by the `%` operation. It should work fine if you remove both occurences.

If I compile the code above with `cython` the generated C code contains the following line

```
int * __pyx_parallel_temp1 = 1;
```

which causes the problem, since `int` is assigned to `int*`.

I assume that you compile with `g++` which raises an error in this case. Using `gcc` only issues a warning on my system which should be fine. Alternatively, you can pass the flag `-fpermissive` to `g++` to get it work.

Thus, the following worked for me:

```
cython code.pxy
g++ code.c -c `pkg-config --libs --cflags python2` -fpermissive
```

As does:

```
cython code.pxy
gcc code.c -c `pkg-config --libs --cflags python2`
```

Comment: Used the -fpermissive flag to get it working...thanks :)......should the bug be filed.